# Change some text in reset password mail in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

I have used default authentication by using the artisan comment

> php artisan make:auth

It has forgot password button to reset user password. Its working fine but i need to change some of the text in Password reset mail. For example the **Hello** text and **Regards** text in the password reset mail.

By using the comment `php artisan make:notification MyResetPassword` i can override the existing mail template but to change only two text i dont want to do that much changes.

There is a file to change some mail body lines in `ResetPassword.php` in `toMail` method. I need to know how can i change **Hello** and **Regards** text by using this method (**toMail()**).

I have changed my mail subject line like below.

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Company of Good Portal Dashboard - Reset Password')
        ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset for your COG Portal – CMS account.')
        ->action('Reset Password', url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
        ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Aplikasi Peminjaman Cimahi Techno Park - Reset Password')
            ->greeting('Hello')
            ->line('Anda menerima email ini karena kami menerima permintaan reset password untuk akun anda.')
            ->action('Reset Password', url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
            ->line('Jika anda tidak mengirimkan permintaan untuk reset password, abaikan email ini.')
            ->salutation('Terima Kasih,')
            ->salutation('Cimahi Techno Park');
    }
```